# Disable warning: the `gets' function is dangerous in GCC through header files?

Tags: c, gcc, header, warnings, gets

I am using the function `gets()` in my C code.
My code is working fine but I am getting a warning message

```
(.text+0xe6): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
```

I want this warning message not to pop up. Is there any way?

I am wondering that there might be such possibilities by creating a header file for disabling some warnings. Or is there any option during compiling that can serve my purpose? Or may be there is a particular way of using `gets()` for this warning not to pop up?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The obvious answer is to learn from what the compiler is trying to tell you - you should never, ever, use gets(), as it is totally unsafe. Use [fgets()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead, which allows you to prevent possible buffer overruns.

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 100
char buff[BUFFER_SIZE];
gets( buff);   // unsafe!
fgets( buff, sizeof(buff), stdin );   // safe
```

Comment: In real life you will probably want to use `sizeof buff` instead of duplicating the buffer size.

Comment: In real life you will want to size the buffer via a constant such as BUFFSIZE and also use that in the fgets() call.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question.

Answer (score 25):

If you really want use it.

Here is answer From: http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=523641

If you use a reasonably recent version of gcc, you can use:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "your option here"
```

For example, if those headers produce a "floating point comparison is unsafe" error, you would use:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wfloat-equal".
```

Unluckily, you cannot disable "-Wall" that way (that would be too easy, wouldn't it...), you have to do the individual warning options which -Wall enables by hand (at least, the conflicting ones).

Docs: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas

**EDIT:**
But it seems not work for gets warning...  I tried on my pc.

Comment: +1 Although I agree that gets() must not be used, you are the only one who actually answered OP's question :)

Comment: This only works for diagnostics issued by the *compiler*.  The "gets is unsafe" message comes from the *linker* and AFAIK there is no way to disable it.

Answer (score 9):

I would heed the warning and replace `gets`. This is clear enough for me:

> BUGS
>
> Never use gets().  Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in
>   advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to store
>   characters  past  the  end  of  the  buffer,  it  is extremely dangerous to use.  It has 
>   been used to break computer security.  Use fgets() instead.

Answer (score 9):

Use fgets() instead of gets()

```
char buffer[BUFSIZ];
/* gets(buffer); */
fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer), stdin);
```

The gets() function does not check the length of buffer and can write past the end and alter the stack. This is the "buffer overflow" you hear about.

Answer (score 6):

There really is no good reason to use `gets()`. Even the C standard says it's obsolescent! Use `fgets()` instead.

[Edit]

It looks like the warning comes from the linker. Do you get warning when compiling with `-c`? (Which disables linking.)

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use the `gets` function at all, the manpage says to use `fgets` instead.

GCC does not provide the functionality that GCC does to disable warnings using pragmas. You must use the various [warning options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) as flags to the compiler instead.

Comment: This warning is given by the linker.  I don't know a way to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest a safe substitute for `gets()`.

In existing code, to substitute `gets()`, it may not be desired to use `fgets()` as that function requires an additional `char` to save the `'\n'` which both functions consume, but `gets()` does not save.  Following is a substitute that does not require a larger buffer size.

Each `gets(dest)` is replace with:
If `dest` is an array, use `gets_sz(dest, sizeof dest)`
If `dest` is a pointer to an `char` array of size `n`, use `gets_sz(dest, n)`

```
char *gets_sz(char *dest, size_t size) {
    if (size <= 1) {
        if (size <= 0 || feof(stdin)) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    size--;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int ch = getchar();
        if (ch == EOF) {
            if (i == 0)
                return NULL;
            break;
        }
        if (ch == '\n')
            break;
        dest[i] = (char) ch;
    }
    dest[i] = 0;
    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`-fno-stack-protector` is an option that allows the `gets()` function to be used in spite of how unsafe it is.

`-Wno-deprecated-declarations` turns off the deprecation warning

Here's an example of compiling with `gets()`

```
gcc myprogram.c -o myprogram -fno-stack-protector -Wno-deprecated-declarations
```

I agree with everyone who says that it's completely unsafe since it will allow a program to overrun a buffer. This can be quite dangerous and hence the reason it has been deprecated in favor of fgets.

However, if you're taking an intro to security course, being able to write a small test program to play with the concepts of buffer overrun and stack overflows is very helpful.

Comment: I think security education is definitely an exception (the only exception?) to everyone's strident objections. Anyway, now that C11 has removed `gets` from the library, even this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use it, try the flag `-fsyntax-only`.

The manual in [gcc website](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html) says:

> `-fsyntax-only`
>
> ```
> Check the code for syntax errors, but don't do anything beyond that.
> ```

Answer (score -4):

Contrary to popular opinion, not all programmers are equally inattentive to what they are writing.  `gets()` will always be standard in C90, and it was put in the library for several good reasons.  It's no more "dangerous" than any other string function when used appropriately, such as in program examples, documentation, unit test scaffolding, homework assignments, etc.

What's more, `gets()` enhances readability in a way that `fgets()` never will.  And one never has to interrupt one's train of thought to look up what order to put its arguments in.

The following workaround uses my other favorite function to remove the newline.  :)

```
 #define gets GET_LOST
 #include "stdio.h"
 #undef gets

 #include "limits.h"

 char *gets(char *s)
 {
    return strtok(fgets(s, INT_MAX, stdin), "\n");
 }
```

Comment: Who signs a SO answer with their name, phone number, and a date?

Comment: If user input consist only of `'\n'`, this routine returns `NULL`.  Original `gets()` returned `""`.