# Using gcc to compile my program with gets function

Tags: c, string

Whenever I try to do that, I get this :

> warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used

now , I know why this function is awful. But for the sake of compiling my already-written program, I must use this function. What should I do so this warning won't appear? [or a function with the EXACT same properties. fgets is slightly different so my code won't work]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214365/disable-warning-messages-in-gcc-through-header-files

Comment: Can you elaborate why you "must" use `gets`?

Comment: I agree with Scooter, but personally, i'd leave the warning in there as a reminder for when you get some more round tuits. Using the gets function is unsafe, forgetting you've used the gets functions is unsafer.

Comment: I must use gets because the program i wrote depends on char arrays that are strings looking like this : somethingsomething\0 
in fgets you have somethingsomething[character for NL]\0

Comment: @michael Here are three questions that explain why `gets` is bad. [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843073/warninggets-function-is-dangerous) and [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214365/disable-warning-messages-in-gcc-through-header-files). It's been deprecated for quite a long time now. You should consider rewriting your program, or post code in the question for context.

Comment: remyabel - I need a function that gets a string "" to a char array and puts \0 in the end of it. do you know anything like that ?(fgets do no fit)

Comment: Your assumption that `gets` returns different content to `fgets` is correct, but it's trivial to overwrite the terminating `\n` with a `NUL` character.

Comment: @Scooter The question you refer OP to explains why `gets()` is a bad idea but it does not explain how to get rid of the warning. Not useful.

Comment: @FUZxxl The way to get rid of the warning is to **stop using the function**.

Comment: @duskwuff False. There are good reasons to keep a program unchanged.

Comment: @FUZxxl Then you live with the warning. It doesn't prevent the program from compiling, linking, or running; it just notifies you that the program is unsafe.

Comment: @duskwuff It clutters the output and hides other warnings.

Comment: Your program has a bug. It uses `gets`, and therefore cannot defend against long input lines. What are your circumstances that make it impossible to fix that bug? Note that `gets` has been removed from the language as of the 2011 ISO C standard; a conforming impelmentation is not obligated to compile and link your program at all.

Comment: @FUZxxl: there is **no reason** to not change a program to stop using `gets`. `gets` is so broken that it was removed from ISO C11. It is so broken that it is the only function ever removed from the ISO C standard.

Comment: @ninjalj Not being allowed to change a program is a fairly good reason.

Comment: @FUZxxl There is an answer that does give a link that allegedly shows how to disable it. Unfortunately, after making my comment I found out that the link is now dead. That answer also talked about using pragmas to disable warning messages.

Comment: You can write a replacement function that works the same way but will not read more than **N** characters, for whatever value of **N** happens to be appropriate. (Don't call it `gets`; prior C11 that was a standard library function, and redefining that name causes undefined behavior.)

Answer (score 1):

You should not suppress the warning.  If you truly feel that you cannot live with the warning, write a simple script that parses the output and discards the warning and name it suitably so that you build with:

```
make ... | I-am-fully-cognizant-of-the-fact-that-this-program-uses-an-unsafe-function-and-the-resulting-executable-is-completely-unsafe
```

It would be unwise to shorten the name of the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Moved answer to

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27431134/2410359

Will delete this after a bit.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried compiling with `-w` to disable warnings?

Comment: Dear downvoter, please tell me how my answer does not solve OPs problem (i.e. disabling the warning).