# Count number of same letters in a string

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I have been reading "The C Programming Language" and I got to this problem, that my output is `0` for any given string I send.

My function looks like this:

```
 int number_of_repeating(char *word,char k){
    int b=0,len=0,i;
    gets(word);
    len=strlen(word);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(word[i]==k)
        b++;
    }
    return  b;
}
```

**Problem**:

I send him word for example: `Jhonny`, and character `n`, so it should count number of n's in the word (in this case the output should be 2).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please format question properly and stick to the actual language you are using. Thanks.

Comment: can you show how the code is called?

Comment: If you pass "Johnny" as an argument, you don't need `gets`, just remove that line completely.

Comment: `number=bnumber_of_repeating(word,c);` word is entered above, and character is entered above like this : `printf("enter a word"); scanf("%s",word); printf("enter a character"); scanf("%c",&c);`

Comment: @Michael Update the question itself. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27429810/edit

Comment: @Ishamael answered. THanks. yeah i dont need gets(word) if im passing the word already.

Comment: @Michael In you comment above you call bnumber_of_repeating(word,c) where as initially you declare number_of_repeating(word,c). Are you probably calling wrong method?

Comment: Just [don't ever use `gets()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2843073/10077), even if you do need to get input. Use fgets()` or something else that's capable of being used safely.

Comment: @FredLarson and when is the best situation to use `gets()` ? can you give some example. thanks

Comment: @Michael: There IS NO SITUATION in which you should use `gets()`. Never. Pretend it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Michael There is no _direct_ substitute for `gets()`.  Use alternatives like `fgets()` or `getline()`.  They have slightly different approaches concerning buffers as compared to `gets()` which simply assumes there is enough space for all user input.

Comment: @chux is it okay to use `scanf("%s",string)` and then `strcpy()` instead of getline or fgets?

Comment: @Michael Not really.  Same problems.  Many folks, including myself, avoid `scanf()`.  Further, `scanf("%s",string)` and `gets()` have different functionality.  `scanf("%s",string)` only saves non-white-space input and `gets()` reads up to `'\n'`, including other white-space.  I have a candidate `gets()` substitute at http://stackoverflow.com/a/27429750/2410359  Certainly many exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int number_of_repeating(char *word,char k){
    int b=0,len=0,i;
    gets(word); //<------- You need to remove this one because it may overwrite
    len=strlen(word);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(word[i]==k)
        b++;
    }
    return  b;
}
int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    printf("%d",number_of_repeating("johnny",'n'));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're passing the string in there is no reason to call gets(), that could be it or your types could be wrong.