# How can I get a string from input without including a newline using fgets?

Tags: c, newline, stdin, fgets

I'm trying to write an inputted string elsewhere and do not know how to do away with the new line that appears as part of this string that I acquire with stdin and fgets.

```
 char buffer[100];
 memset(buffer, 0, 100);
 fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
 printf("buffer is: %s\n stop",buffer);
```

I tried to limit the amount of data that fgets gets as well as limiting how much of the data is written but the new line remains. How can I simply get the inputted string up to the last character written with nothing else?

Comment: `scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", buffer);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", buffer)` will not read anything into `buffer` if the first `char` is `'\n'`. The `'\n'` remains in `stdin`.

Comment: Do you want to read a line and leave the `'\n'` in the input stream, or do you want to read a line including the `'\n'` and then discard the `'\n'`? (This will affect the next input operation, which will or will not see the `'\n'` waiting for it.)

Answer (score 5):

try

```
fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
size_t ln = strlen(buffer)-1;
if (buffer[ln] == '\n')
    buffer[ln] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply look for the potential `'\n'`.

After calling `fgets()`, If `'\n'` exists, it will be the last `char` in the string (just before the `'\0'`).

```
size_t len = strlen(buffer);
if (len > 0 && buffer[len-1] == '\n') {
  buffer[--len] = '\0';
}
```

---

Sample usage

```
char buffer[100];
// memset(buffer, 0, 100); not needed
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) { // good to test fgets() result
  Handle_EOForIOerror();
}
size_t len = strlen(buffer);
if (len > 0 && buffer[len-1] == '\n') {
  buffer[--len] = '\0';
}
printf("buffer is: %s\n stop",buffer);
```

Notes:

`buffer[strlen(buffer)-1]` is dangerous in rare occasions when the first `char` in `buffer` is a `'\0'` (embedded null character).

`scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", buffer);` is a problem if the first `char` is `'\n'`, nothing is read and `'\n'` remains in `stdin`.

`strlen()` is fast as compared to other methods: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/67756/29485

Or roll your own code like [`gets_sz`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27431134/2410359)