# Loop while double not equal character?

Tags: c, double, character

I'm not really sure how to execute this...

```
double fahrenheit;

fahrenheit = 0;

while (fahrenheit != "q")
```

I'm going to use a scanf to get the value of fahrenheit.
fahrenheit is a double and q is a character so obviously it isn't really liking it... 
Can someone please tell me how to make this one work?

---

Thank you guys for trying and explaining it to me but I'm really in the early stages of learning C or just programming in general. It's a simple exercise in our book and I haven't really learned all those stuff yet.
Basically, if they input q, nothing happens. If they input anything else but q, something happens. 
Is there like a REALLY SIMPLE like 1+1=2 kind of simple formula here for me to execute this?

Comment: Read as a string, check for e.g. `"q"` and if it's not then attempt to [convert to `double`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof).

Answer (score 2):

`scanf()` shown below returns 0 when you pass character so when you enter `q` while loop will terminate

```
double fahrenheit;
while(scanf("%lf",&fahrenheit) == 1)
{
 // Do your stuff
}
```

Else

1. Read the input into `char` array using `fgets()`
2. Use `strcmp()` to check whether the input is `q`
3. If the input is not `q` use `strtod()` to convert string to double and assign that value to your variable.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do it is to read a line of text, and parse it to see if it's the `q` letter or if it can be converted to a number, something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char line[100];

    printf("Enter Temperatur (F) > ");
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        size_t length;
        double fahrenheit;
        char *endptr;
        /* get the length of the input string */
        length = strlen(line);
        if (length == 0)
            return -1;
        if (line[length - 1] == '\n') /* remove the '\n' possibly read by fgets */
            line[--length] = '\0';
        /* check if the input string equals "q" */
        if (strcmp(line, "q") == 0)
            return 0;
        /* convert the input string to a double */
        fahrenheit = strtod(line, &endptr);
        /* check if the conversion was successful */
        if (*endptr != '\0')
        {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return -1;
        }
        printf("value = %f\n", fahrenheit);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

you can retry on invalid input and process other commands too apart from `"q"` if you need to, this gives you more control on the input.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491005/how-can-i-get-a-string-from-input-without-including-a-newline-using-fgets

Comment: @Gopi Sure you can write an `fgets()` imitation that skips the `'\n'` but using the existing one and removing it afterwards is I think, a simple solution.

Comment: @Gopi sure, I can't think if that's possible now because I am busy working, but you are probably right, although I think in such case, `fgets()` would return `NULL` which i checked.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution with minimal error checking.

Read user input as a string.
Test if `q` was entered.
Otherwise convert to `double`.

```
double fahrenheit;
while (1) { // repeat forever
  char buffer[100];
  fputs("Enter temperature in Fahrenheit:", stdout);
  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) break;  // exit on IO error or EOF
  if (buffer[0] == 'q') break; 
  if (sscanf(buffer, "%lf", &fahrenheit) == 1) {  // was scan successful?
    printf("Success: %f\n", fahrenheit);
  } else {
    printf("Failed: '%s'\n", buffer);
  }
}
```

What is missing for a robust solution:
1) Distinguish between leaving the loop due to `q` or `EOF`.
2) Will quit loop on "q", "quit", "qxyz", but not quit on "Q", " q".
3) Will succeed on input like "123 C".
4) No degree range check  like failing for "-1000".
5) Does not complain about crazy input > 100 `char`s.